# Spark Parquet file writing will not show any files in target folder

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am facing a wired situation. I am trying to read from oracle and write to a hdfs folder in parquet files using spark-sql 2.3.1. Below is my code snippet:

```
df.write.format("parquet")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .partitionBy(partitionColumn)
  .save(parquet_file)
```

When I run this code in locally it is working fine, but when I run the same on a apache-spark cluster it is not at producing any results in the target folder.

Not sure what is missing but I don't see any errors in logs. Quite interestingly when I reduce the number of records of oracle table it is producing the folders as expected. How to solve this problem?

Comment: parquet_file here is the path of target folder for saving parquet files.

Comment: Check 2 Things
1. Count of Dataframe that you are writing - does it have any data?
2. Can you print path where you are writing i.e parquet_file and path where you are checking files. just want to make sure you have not messed up relative path

Comment: @HarjeetKumar 1. I have lot of data in the table , the respected dataframe has around 1793,723594  i.e. 1790 million records.  2.  When I read fewer records i.e. 1 million records I can see the files in target path , but when I read entire records i dont see any files in the target path.  So its not the path issue.

Comment: @BdEngineer Are you still facing the issue? Where is your target folder?